# Persistence value is not correct in the code

Tags: c, arrays

I am working on a program in C which is supposed to dynamically allocate memory to a 2d array of [x] rows and [y] columns with the help of malloc(). The things I was supposed to to do for this program are :

- Create space to hold [r] x [c] integers.
- Use a nested **for loop** to fill the array space.
- Each cell needs to be assigned with the number **i + j**
- You need to keep track of your own offset by **i*c + j** within a single subscript.
- Walk the entire array and add up each element to form the sum.

This is how I have approached the problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  int r;
  int c;
  int sum = 0;
  int i;
  int j;
  int *A;

  printf("Enter number of rows : \n");
  scanf("%d", &r);
  printf("Enter number of columns : \n");
  scanf("%d", &c);

  A = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * r * c);

  printf("Enter the array elements : ");
  for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
  {
      for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
      {
          scanf("%d", &(*(A + i * c + j)));
          sum += (*(A + i * c + j));
      }
  }
  printf("The sum is : %d", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

As far as the code is, it works properly when compiled by allocating 2 bytes per integer for each slot in the integer array, but when I submit this same code to Bottlenose (Web based assignment submission for CS based courses), I am given these two prompts

```
not ok 1 - Test 1 FAILED: Did not print sum properly.
not ok 2 - Test 2 FAILED: Did not allocated and free 
correct amount of memory with one call to malloc and one call to free.
```

What exactly am  I doing wrong in my program?

Comment: "Did not allocated and free". That one is likely because you did not call `free`. For the first one, you have not given us the exact requirements so we don't know whether the requirement actually needs you to print `"The sum is"` part of the output or just the integer sum value.

Comment: There is no 2D array (heck, is this "let's call everything a 2D array" day?)

Comment: Persistence normally refers to values saved on disk (in a database, in a file, or something similar).  Your question is not self-evidently about persistence.

Comment: @kaylum Yes, the program also has to bring "The sum is" also with the sum of all array values.

Comment: @kaylum I edited the code and used free() function on my pointer *A, which makes my test 2 pass, but test one is still incorrect

Comment: Can you provide the test input that causes the incorrect output?

Comment: @M.M The input which causes the incorrect output is the array values which the user needs to input for addition

Comment: Don't the assignment instructions say that the value in each cell has to be calculated (sum of row number plus column number)?  Not the result of `scanf()`...  You should probably add a newline at the end of the final `printf()`.  And, were it me, I'd write `&A[i * c + j]` in preference to `&(*(A + i * c + j)))`.  It's a lot simpler to read and harder to get wrong.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Now that I see it, you are right about the formatting. I'll keep this in mind the next time I format. Thanks for your tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I read your problem statement, it appears you are confusing the directions. Specifically:

> ```
> Each cell needs to be assigned with the number i + j
> ```

You are also told to **"keep track of your own offset by i*c + j within a single subscript"**. Which would imply a simple assignment of the value of `i + j` to the offset `array[i * c + j]`, which would imply:

```
array[i * c + j] = i + j;
```

Further, as indicated in the comments, you are NOT allocating a 2D array, you are allocating a block of memory of sufficient SIZE to hold `r * c` **integer** values. Whether you index values in that block sequentially (as a simple array) or index them as a *simulated* 2D array is entirely up to you, but the underlying block of memory is simply an allocated block of `r * c * sizeof *array` bytes.

Putting those pieces together, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {   /* you don't use any argument, use void */

    int *array, r, c, sum = 0;  /* declare, initialize variables */

    printf ("enter number of rows: ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &r) != 1) {    /* alway validate ALL input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid row value.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("enter number of cols: ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &c) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid column value.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate & VALIDATE -- often useful to initialize to zero with calloc */
    if (!(array = calloc (r * c, sizeof *array))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)          /* nested loops */
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            array[i * c + j] = i + j;    /* assign i + j to correct address */
            sum += array[i * c + j];     /* add value to sum */
        }

    printf ("The sum is : %d\n", sum);

    free (array);   /* if you allocate it, track it and free it when done */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arrayalloc
enter number of rows: 4
enter number of cols: 4
The sum is : 48
```

If you print the values in the simulated 2D array, you will get:

```
$ ./bin/arrayalloc
enter number of rows: 4
enter number of cols: 4
   0   1   2   3
   1   2   3   4
   2   3   4   5
   3   4   5   6
The sum is : 48
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions. If you are interested in outputting the values as a simulated 2D array using you single subscript index, you can do something similar to:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {       /* nested loops */
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            array[i * c + j] = i + j;   /* assign i + j to correct offset */
            sum += array[i * c + j];    /* add value to sum */
            printf (" %3d", array[i * c + j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }
```

Also note the requirement:

> ```
> Walk the entire array and add up each element to form the sum.
> ```

could imply separate nested-initialization and summing loops requiring you to "walk the entire array" using a pointer to sum the values. In that case you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {   /* you don't use any argument, use void */

    int *array, *p, r, c, sum = 0;  /* declare, initialize variables */

    printf ("enter number of rows: ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &r) != 1) {    /* alway validate ALL input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid row value.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("enter number of cols: ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &c) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid column value.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate & VALIDATE */
    if (!(array = calloc (r * c, sizeof *array))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    p = array;  /* assign array to pointer */

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)         /* nested loops used to initialize */
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            array[i * c + j] = i + j;   /* assign i + j to correct offset */

    for (int i = 0; i < r * c; i++, p++)  /* separate loop to walk the array */
        sum += *p;                        /* sum values using pointer */

    printf ("The sum is : %d\n", sum);

    free (array);   /* if you allocate it, track it and free it when done */

    return 0;
}
```

That is more a matter of semantics, but using separate initialization and summing loops and using a pointer to walk the array complies more closely to your instructions.

Comment: May I know as of why would you use **fprintf()** instead of **printf()** to print statement? in your first solution?

Comment: Sure, whenever you are issuing warnings or errors, you want those printed on `stderr` instead of the normal `stdout`. Since `printf` outputs by default to `stdout`, you use `fprintf` to print to `stderr` (or any other file stream). It's really just a matter of doing it right. If you attempt to collect output by redirecting the output of your program, you often do not want warnings, etc.. in the output you capture. (e.g. `./myprog >> my_logfile.txt`) If you use `fprintf` to `stderr` for warnings and errors, only output goes to `my_logfile.txt` and warnings/errors go to the screen.